# `pytest -rP` got error while `pytest` didn't to run Selenium with Django and pytest-django on Windows 11

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, windows-11, pytest-django

I set `tests/test_ex1.py` as shown below. *I use [Django 4.2.1](https://github.com/django/django), [pytest-django 4.5.2](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Selenium 4.11.2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) on Windows 11:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |-my_app2
 └-tests
    |-__init__.py
    └-test_ex1.py # Here
```

Then, I defined `test_example()` with `print("OK")` to test Django Admin in `TestBrowser1` class as shown below:

```py
# "tests/test_ex1.py"

from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver

class TestBrowser1(LiveServerTestCase):
    def test_example(self):
        print("OK")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, "/admin/")))
        assert "Log in | Django site admin" in driver.title
```

Then, I could successfully run **Selenium** with `pytest` by not printing `OK` as shown below:

```
$ pytest
===================================== test session starts =====================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
django: settings: core.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-19.3.0, django-4.5.2, factoryboy-2.5.1
collected 1 item                                                                               

tests\test_ex6.py
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56055/devtools/browser/271a3af7-5697-47e5-a7db-fd80c52ed70d
.                                                                      [100%]

====================================== 1 passed in 5.11s ======================================
```

But, I could not successfully run **Selenium** with `pytest -rP` by getting the error below even though it printed `OK`. *`pytest -s`, `pytest --capture=no` and `pytest --capture=tee-sys` also got the same error below even though it printed `OK` as well:

```
$ pytest -rP
===================================== test session starts =====================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.4.0, pluggy-1.2.0
django: settings: core.settings (from ini)
rootdir: C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: Faker-19.3.0, django-4.5.2, factoryboy-2.5.1
collected 1 item                                                                               

tests\test_ex6.py
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56086/devtools/browser/2003bd23-8794-414d-805a-79faacf9a82b
.                                                                      [100%]

=========================================== PASSES ============================================ 
__________________________________ TestBrowser1.test_example __________________________________ 
------------------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------------------- 
OK
------------------------------------ Captured stderr call ------------------------------------- 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1723, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 124, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1706, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 1718, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 34, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "C:\Users\kai\test-django-project2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "C:\Users\kai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join    
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
[17/Aug/2023 08:57:52,267] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56096)
[17/Aug/2023 08:57:52,268] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56097)
====================================== 1 passed in 5.18s ======================================
```

So, how can I successfully run **Selenium** with `pytest -rP` by not getting the error and by printing `OK`?